# PFObject subclass, unrecognized selector sent to instance with NSMutableArray attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, pfobject

I'm subclassing PFObject like that

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SomeClass : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic) PFUser* user;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray* arrayOfOtherClasses;

+ (void) load;
+ (NSString*) parseClassName;
```

Then I create my object and save it to Parse database

```
SomeClass* someClassInstance = [SomeClass object];
someClassInstance.arrayOfOtherClasses = [NSMutableArray new];
[someClassInstance.arrayOfOtherClasses addObject:[OtherClass object]]; ...

[someClassInstance saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                // ....
            }];
```

It save well data in Parse database. But when I try to retrieve data, my app crashes when I'm doing

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SomeClass"];
[query includeKey:@"user"];
[query includeKey:@"arrayOfOtherClasses"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        for(SomeClass* someClass in results){
            NSMutableArray* array = someClass.arrayOfOtherClasses; // CRASH
        }
    }
}];
```

with the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SomeClass arrayOfOtherClasses]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you have in your SomeClass.m file? Do you have he @dynamic statements for each of your properties?

Comment: Yes, I have the @dynamic statements